# C# compile finalize method's on runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, clr

As im reading through 3 books about GC  , ive notice some strange fact :

*C# via CLR*

`CriticalFinalizerObject` : *the CLR treats this class and classes derived from it in a very special manner*

[image]

what ???

"not find enough memory to **COMPILE a method?** " IMHO - the code should be already compiled... no ?

when Im writing c# code - the whole code is compiled to IL before its running... no?
but according to the text - at *RUNTIME* - he *MAY find insufficient memory for compile*...

Help ?

Comment: This perfectly explains why Finalize is not guaranteed to be executed, so don't be panic easily :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JIT compiler only compiles methods from IL to native code at runtime the first time they are executed. As you might expect, this requires extra memory. So, normal finalizers are only compiled right before they are exeucted by the cleanup thread.

An object derived from `CriticalFinalizerObject` has it's finalizer compiled immediately, so no extra memory is required to execute it at program shutdown. This is for objects that *must* have their finalizer executed if at all possible (nonwithstanding a power cut or similar)

Comment: in what situation MUST MUST MUST finilizer to be run ? finilizers are for Unmanaged resources which WILL (eventually)  be reclaimed when the OS gets back its control ...

Comment: During process shutdown there is no reason. This makes sense in an environment where many AppDomains are used and from time to time unloaded like a web server. This helps to survive the server process longer if and only if the appdomain is not unladed due to an unhandled exeption.

Comment: @AloisKraus `helps to survive the server process longer ` I can't see the whole picture. sorry. lets say I have A,B,C,D app domains. what does `CriticalFinalizerObject ` help me here ( running `CriticalFinalizerObject `) I need a REAL life example so I can understand and not a book definition. Can you please answer ?

Comment: During appdomain shutdown the finalizers have a timeout (it was once 2s) after that the critical finalizers are executed. The whole reason for the SafeHandles to derive from CriticalFinalizerObject is to ensure closing the handle even in the case of a misbehaving finalizer which blocks the shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the backend of the 'Compiler'. From the IL to the Machine code.

Comment: You should say JIT compiler to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

With compiler is the JIT compiler meant to compile your finalizer methods eagerly and not to delay its compilation shortly before it is executed.

The deeper reason behind it is that these finalizers are called during application shutdown after all normal finalizers were executed. But the CLR does execute all pending finalizers with a timeout of 2s (at least this was it with .NET 2.0 have not checked since then again). Then the critical finalizers are executed.

Critial finalizer have rare uses e.g. for handles which need to be closed in any case. But you can also use them to hold resources open until all finalizers are executed to enable e.g. [tracing even inside finalizers](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2006/06/12/81629.aspx).